# How to get joined entrys last when grouping by some columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-select-db

my table is filled with private messages
if i GROUP BY to_id i just get the oldest entry
i need the newest entry first

here is what i tried...

```
SELECT t1.date
     , t2.nick
     , t1.to_id
     , t3.message
     , xis_checked ,COUNT(*) AS subject
  FROM private_messages t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN private_messages_text t3
    ON t1.private_messages_text_id = t3.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN members t2 
    ON t1.members_id = t2.id 
 WHERE members_id = '1027' 
 GROUP 
    BY t1.to_id DESC
```

i  hope you understood what i tried

the newer entries have a checked value of 0 and that's what i need, The date should also be the last in table for the specified members_id

i forgot the COUNT(*) in my question
if i group then he shows all entries

Answer (score 0):

You should use ORDER BY

```
SELECT t1.date,t2.nick,t1.to_id,t3.message,xis_checked FROM private_messages t1 LEFT JOIN private_messages_text t3
ON t1.private_messages_text_id=t3.id LEFT JOIN members t2 
ON t1.members_id=t2.id WHERE members_id='1027' 
ORDER BY t1.to_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Order BY** help us here!

```
//query
GROUP BY t1.to_id
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: found solution with `max(date)` and `min(checked)`

Comment: Supr. max(date) results in one entry.